# Fix focus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to fix a focus on input field until, say, user enters 4 characters?
The reason I need it is because i don't have a background for my text area (stylistic purpose)
and if user clicks on a random place on my page it will be hard for many users to locate the text area.

Here is my text field and button

```
<div id="inputtext">
      <input type="text" id="dreamtext" autofocus/>
      <input type="submit" id="nextstepbutton" value="next step" onclick="window.open('step3.html','_self','resizable=yes')" />
    </div>
```

I already have some scripts going on which hides the button and changes some div when there are less then 4 characters in text field. It would be super great if I could also implement permanent focus in this script.

```
$(function(){
     $("#nextstepbutton").hide();

     $("#dreamtext").keyup(function() {
         var val = $(this).val();
         if (val.length > 3) {
             $('#nextstepbutton').show();
             document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<h1>press 'enter' key or next step</h1>";
         }
         else {
             $('#nextstepbutton').hide();
             document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<h1>type please</h1>";
         }

     });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should really avoid *creating* a problem like this in the first place. A solution to it, to the extent it works, would create a new problem by locking the user in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `blur()`, the opposite of `focus()`...

```
$('#dreamtext').on('blur',function(){
   if (this.value.length < 4) this.focus();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzw72/)

Comment: Nice, this is even better. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('dreamtext').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.value.length > 3 || this.focus(); 
});
```

Use the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur) event. It triggers when focus is lost.

Comment: @bjb568 binding lots of event is not a good idea for this. A better one is to use `blur()`.. check my anwser

Answer (score 0):

Using a event listener you could do something like

```
 $('#textbox').change(function(){

    if ( $(this).val().length <= 4 ) {

        $(this).css('border', '1px solid orange');

    } else {

        $(this).css('border', '0');

    }

});
```

When the user initially clicks the box it'll have a 'orange' border until it has 4 or more characters, indicating it needs attention.